# Display elements of a String which are not found on the other

Tags: java, string

We were told to do a program on stings and I wasn't able to attend class because I was sick. I am asking for your help on this task that was given to us.

Create a java program that will ask the user to input two Strings. Compare the two strings and display the letters that are found on the first string but are not found on the second string.

Here is what I have at the moment https://pastebin.com/7a4dHecR

I really have no Idea what to do so any help would be appreciated!

https://pastebin.com/7a4dHecR

```
import java.util.*;
public class filename{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Input first string: ");
        String one=sc.next();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Input second string: ");
        String two=sc.next();
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- I recommend contacting your instructor/professor/teacher. --- Please read: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) --- You forgot to ask an actual question. Please [edit] the post and add a focused question.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Try reading about the concepts that were taught in the class the day you were not able to attend and make your way forward from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I'm going to give you some parts you can put together. They are not the shortest or simplest way to solve this particular problem, but they will be useful for other small programs you write.

Here are some hints:

First, figure out how to step through your code with a debugger.
Second, figure out how to find the Javadoc for Java library classes and their methods.

You need to do something for each character in a string. Use a for loop for that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < one.length(); i++) {
 // your code here
}
```

You need to get a particular character of a `String`.

```
String c = one.substring(i, i+1);
```

Read the Javadoc for `String.substring` to understand what the `i` and `i+1` parameters do.

Now you need to find a way to check whether a `String` `contains` another `String`. Look at the Javadoc for the `String` class.

Then you can put all this together.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following:

```
String diff: StringUtils.difference(one, two);
System.out.println(diff);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge and how our solution overcomes it. --- The code presented will not compile.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Sorry!